# How to make Android Studio use my build.gradle template for a new project?

Tags: android, templates, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I make a build.gradle to increment prod version code on release build and some other config that I want for all my futur projects, is there a way to tell Android Studio (or intelliJ) to use my build.gradle for all new project I create ? 
Or maybe is there a template use by IDE for gradle file I can modify?

Comment: `android_sdk/tools/templates` ?

Comment: Did find where I can add my code... Try on sdk\tools\templates\projects\NewAndroidApplication\root\build.gradle.fft but when I create a project nothing is added

Answer (score 6):

I have found that android studio does not use the templates from the sdk directory. I have found the template in :

```
<android-studio>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject/root/build.gradle.ftl
```

you could try putting your gradle functions in here and android studio should pick them up for every new Android application project

Answer (score 1):

```
→ ~/../../sdk/tools/android create project 
--activity MainActivity 
--package com.example.android 
--target 3 
--path ~/AndroidStudioProjects/Example
--gradle YOUR_GRADLE_TEMLATE_PATH
```

to see details:

```
→ ~/../../sdk/tools/android -h
```