# How auto-import libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, libraries, butterknife

Android Studio can be configured to automatically import libs that I use in all my projects? For example, I use butterknife, but it is tedious to have to modify the file build.gradle every time I create a new project. 
I would take the method of that every time you create a project this library is already set in Gradle files.

Comment: Perhaps the answers on this post would help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253595/how-to-make-android-studio-use-my-build-gradle-template-for-a-new-project